# Can you acquire The Infinity Blade other than buying with earned gold?

Tags: ios, infinity-blade

Is there a way to get The Infinity Blade other than finding/earning the roughly 500000 gold required to buy it from the store?

I love the game, but don't fancy a grind-a-thon or in-app purchase to get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to obtain the Infinity Blade sword is with gold, which can either be earned in-game or purchased through the In-App Purchasing system (approximately $20 USD to purchase enough gold to get the sword in-game).

Comment: Man, that's a high dollar-to-pixel ratio.

Comment: I'll update the question if it does show up in a chest when you get the character to a higher level.